# Prove that: $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\geq \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

> Suppose that $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ are  positive real numbers.Also assume that $b_1,b_2,...b_n$ are an arbitrary permutation of $a_i$'s. Prove that: $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\geq \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i.$$

We know that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_i$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nb_i^2$ . I think the  rearrangement inequality can't be used to prove it.Maybe some other classic inequality should be used...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^2_i$, then,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i-b_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^2_i-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i=2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_i-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\geq 0$$

Comment: Bravo,excellent: simple and nice , +1 and accepted

Comment: I agree really elegant +1

Comment: Really smart +1!

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^na_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2$$
since the $b_i$ are a permutation of the $a_i$. Therefore it follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that
$$ \sum_{i}a_ib_i\leq \Big(\sum_ia_i^2\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(\sum_ib_i^2\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sum_ia_i^2$$

Comment: I didn't see the power of $\frac12$ in CS!

Comment: Substituting $a_i$ with $\sqrt{a_i}$, $b_i$ with $\sqrt{b_i}$ in Classical form and both sides taken square roots.
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{a_ib_i}\le\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\sum_{i=1}^n b_i}
\end{align}
Actually for any $\alpha$. $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^+$\begin{align}
\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^\alpha\,y_i^\beta \biggr)^{\alpha+\beta}\le \biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha+\beta} \biggr)^{\alpha}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^{\alpha+\beta}\biggr)^{\beta}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality it's just the Rearrangement (Chebyshov's) inequality.

Let $a_1\geq a_2\geq...\geq a_n$ and $b_1\geq b_2\geq...\geq b_n$.

Thus, for all $\sigma\in S_n$ we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i\geq\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_{\sigma(i)}.$$

Now, take $a_i=b_i$.

Comment: Thank  you,I didn't know about  Chebyshov's inequality,(+1)

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi It's not more inequality, but  It's a very useful method. I am ready to show another examples.